# Add time to date script

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a link on a shop which has certain variables the user must be within before it lets them access a page to add additional item to their order

The code currently lets them access this page 1 day before their delivery date. We would like them to order up to 9pm the day before which is 3 hours before the delivery date.

Does anyone know how to add time to this script? I have changed the -1 days but doesn't work, sorry if I'm asking a noob question. Many thanks!

```
if (($result['payment_code'] == 'cod' )
    && ($result['shipping_code'] == 'xshipping.xshipping1' ) 
    && ($result['delivery_date'] != '0000-00-00' ) 
    && ( time() < strtotime($result['delivery_date'].' -1 days')) ) 
{
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ( $result['payment_code'] == 'cod' ) && ( $result['shipping_code'] == 'xshipping.xshipping1' ) && ( $result['delivery_date'] != '0000-00-00' ) && ( time() < strtotime ('-3 hour', strtotime ($result['delivery_date'])))) ) {
```

This will be true, if current datetime is less than 21:00:00 previous day.

Comment: Oh yes sorry.. but I wanted to change it to 3 hours not 24 hours / 1 day sorry if I didn't explain myself better

Answer (score 0):

try

```
strtotime ('-3 hours', strtotime ($result['delivery_date']));
```

tried like:-

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2014-09-08 15:39:57
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-3 hours', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));//2014-09-08 12:39:57
```

Comment: @Legionar i have checked this my end

Comment: its working also with 's' at the end - http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php